# How can I access unique_ptr from its internal pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I'm coding red-black tree using C++-smart pointers. I designed left and right child to be owned by its parent, so it is `unique_ptr<Node>` member variable of its parent node, and 'parent' member variable is set to be `Node*`, because the children clearly does not have ownership.

**My problem is:** A function that rotates tree takes argument as `unique_ptr<Node>&`, because it changes positions of node, but I need to pass a parent node to the function, which is in type of `Node*` that does not match with function argument type.

The solution I think:

1) Make `parent(`) function that returns `unique_ptr<Node>`. This would be something that starts from the root of the tree and descend to find the pointer that match with parent's address. CONS: slow as hell

2) for `node->parent`, return `node->parent->parent->left` or `right` after some checks.
CONS: code gets little bit messier

3) Make another `unique_ptr<Node>` by giving `Node*` as an argument of constructor, and pass that. CONS: I'm not sure that the newly created unique_ptr object would coincide with already existing `unique_ptr<Node>` object.

4) Use `shared_ptr<Node>` for child, `weak_ptr<Node>` for parent instead. Then I could use `node->parent.lock()` as function argument.
CONS: child pointers' ownership are not meant to be 'shared'.

5) Discard all smart pointer things. Aww.

```
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* parent = nullptr;
    unique_ptr<Node> left, right;
    bool color = false;
    Node(const T& d) : data(d) {};
    Node* grandparent() {
        if (parent == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        return parent->parent;
    }
}

/* SOMETHING... */

void rotate_right(unique_ptr<Node>& pivot) {
    if (pivot->left == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    auto pivot_new = move(pivot->left);
    auto pivot_parent = pivot->parent;
    pivot->left = move(pivot_new->right);
    pivot_new->right = move(pivot);
    pivot->parent = pivot_new.get();
    if (pivot->left != nullptr) {
        pivot->left->parent = pivot.get();
    }
    if (pivot_parent != nullptr) {
        if (pivot == pivot_parent->left) {
            pivot_parent->left = move(pivot_new);
        } else if (pivot == pivot_parent->right) {
            pivot_parent->right = move(pivot_new);
        } else {
            throw invalid_argument("pivot_parent is actually not parent, why?\n");
        }
    }
    pivot_new->parent = pivot_parent;
}

/* SOME OTHER THINGS */

void insert_repair_tree(Node* node) {
    if (node->parent == nullptr) {
        // this is root. paint BLACK
        node->color = true;
    } else if (node->parent->color) {
        // parent is BLACK. tree is valid. do nothing
    } else if (!get_color(node->uncle())) {
        // parent is RED. uncle exists and RED. grandpa exists and BLACK.
        // repaint parent and uncle to BLACK, and grandpa to RED.
        // recursively repair tree at grandpa
        node->parent->color = true;
        node->uncle()->color = true;
        node->grandparent()->color = false;
        insert_repair_tree(node->grandparent());
    } else {
        // parent is RED. uncle is BLACK (not sure that it exists). grandpa exists and BLACK.
        auto grandpa = node->grandparent();
        if (node == grandpa->left->right) {
            rotate_left(grandpa->left);
            node = node->left.get();
        } else if (node == grandpa->right->left) {
            rotate_right(grandpa->right);
            node = node->right.get();
        }
        grandpa = node->grandparent();
        // PROBLEMS HERE 
        if (node == node->parent->left) {
            rotate_right(grandpa);
        } else if (node == node->parent->right) {
            rotate_left(grandpa);
        } else {
            throw invalid_argument("");
        }
        node->parent->color = true;
        grandpa->color = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `rotate_right` taking a normal pointer would be just fine, all your other solutions have much larger problems

Comment: @kmdreko but how..? The 7th line in rotate_right attaches argument pivot pointer to the place of pivot_new->right, whose require type is unique_ptr.

Comment: oops, ignore me, its indeed more complicated than I originally thought

Comment: I would go with your number 2: If you want to switch node A and B, you have to change the pointers in the parents of A and B.

Comment: **3)**  Never ever create a smart pointer from a pointer that is already managed by another smart pointer. That will result in double frees or use after free.

Comment: in order to get the smart pointer from a raw pointer, the only solution is to use a `shared_pointer` and inherit your class from `shared_from_this`

Comment: I would go with 4) and use `shared_ptr` with `shared_from_this` and `weak_ptr`. `shared_ptr`, despite its name, is not *only* used for shared ownership, since it has other features, like the weakness, the ability to get the shared pointer from the raw pointer or (although not in use in you case) the ability to perform type erasure.

Comment: Another option is to have `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` (or just `std::list<Node>`) as ownership *pool* and then use just `Node*`. It is a bit more memory consuming, but will make things like deletion much easier (since default destruction of `Node` is recursive and unless you are lucky with tail recursion optimization, it will blow your stack)

Comment: @Zereges How is a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` list better than manually managing the lifetime of pointers using `new`/ `delete`. Now the `std::list` owns the pointers, and you need to tell the list when those are not required anymore, that looks exactly like requesting/deleting memory from heap .  The deletion can be indeed a problem, but this could also be solved by in the destructor, the destructor could collect all descendant disconnect them and deleted them. Or use a deferred pointer approach with a memory pool.

Comment: I don't have time to think the idea i have in mind through or to write an answer. But is the case that you pass a root node to `rotate_right` even valid? And if so why would it be a problem to write something like `std::unique_ptr<Node> &get_ptr_for_node(Node * n) { if( node->parent->left == n ) { return  node->parent->left;} else if( node->parent->right == n ) { return  node->parent->right;} else { /* some error handling */ }`.

Comment: Why does your rotate function accept a reference to a shared pointer? Where is `pivot` assigned or otherwise changed?

Comment: Thanks for all of your helps. I've decided to go with solution 2), similar with one of  @t.niese

Comment: @n.m. `pivot_new->right = move(pivot);`

Comment: @t.niese can this possibly be correct? `pivot` is dereferenced immediately after that `move`.

Comment: @n.m. I still try to understand what the code actually does. But yes that thats definitely wrong. Both `pivot->parent = ...`  and  `pivot.get()`, but also the `pivot_new->parent = ...`

Comment: @n.m. oops, actually I didn't compiled it yet. then I should add some line like `auto original_pivot = pivot_new->right.get()`. and replace all later `pivot`s into `original_pivot`, or something.

Comment: RB tree rotation always involves changing either a child pointer or a root pointer. What was `...  → 1 → 2 →4` becomes `... → 2 ⇉ ¼`, with former children of 1, 2 and 4 shuffled between new parents. All arrows point down. It makes little sense to say "rotate my parent". You always rotate a *downward link*. Could be a pointer to a root, or a pointer to a left child, or a pointer to a right child.

Comment: It looks like you are following the same implementation from Wikipedia, which is ignoring ownership. I'd be tempted to have a `class RBTree { std::list<Node> nodes; ...};` as the gatekeeper for all operations, at which point you can use `list::iterator`s everywhere.

Comment: @Caleth wikipedia implementation doesn't attempt to change the pivot pointer. It is passed by value there, as it should.

Comment: Another (equivalent) wording of the same thing would be as follows. You are rotating  a *node* (not a pointer) and you are always changing the corresponding pointer of its *parent*. Therefore it makes no sense to pass an owning pointer to that node to the rotate function. Ownership of the pivot changes not through that pointer, but through pivot->parent->left or pivot->parent->right (or root).